# MVC3 Routing and Hash Values, JSon not getting called

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

I currently have a site where I am using Json to populate a dropdownlist based on user input.

When I goto the original site : examples.com/Account/Logon , the json executes fine.
If the user inputs an invalid login MVC replaces my link to : examples.com/Account/LogOn#/Account/LogOn

None of my Json events are executes and the page doesn't work correctly.

Once I am logged in my url then becomes
examples.com/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2f#/Controller

All actions after that then also use the : /Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2f#/Controller logic

My route is :

```
 "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

My Login successful code:

if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\"))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }

My unsuccessful login is:

```
return View(model)
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything that follows the `#` sign (fragment) in an url is never sent to the server by the client browser. This means that the server can never fetch it. Only javascript has access to this portion of the url.

Comment: Is there any reason when my httppost fails and I return the view that my json calls arent executed as if the page had loaded for the first time?

Comment: Is there a reason why when I post and the page reloads none of my json works ?

Comment: @Greg, it's difficult to say without seeing your javascript.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#UserName')
      .click(function () { loadCompanies($(this).val()); })
      .blur(function () { loadCompanies($(this).val()); })
      .keyup(function () { loadCompanies($(this).val()); });
        loadCompanies($("#UserName").val());`


ugh cant get the code block to work
@DarinDimitrov